# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

Tengo un problema al intentar guardar un json en mi base de datos SQlite.
Actualmente estoy utilizando retrofit2 para hacer una peticion GET a mi api php que devuelve el siguiente json. Pero al intentar obtenerlo da el siguiente error: **Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $**

**PD:** Ya busque en varios foros y tambien hice algunas pruebas con JsonArrays desde android pero ninguna me dio resultados

```
    {
  "productos": [
    {
      "pid": "1",
      "detalle": "Cerveza",
      "id_marca": "1",
      "id_rubro": "1",
      "foto": null,
      "descripcion": null,
      "bar_code": null,
      "id_tipo": "1"
    },
    {
      "pid": "2",
      "detalle": "Chocolate con leche",
      "id_marca": "2",
      "id_rubro": "2",
      "foto": null,
      "descripcion": "25g. Chocolate negro",
      "bar_code": null,
      "id_tipo": "4"
    },
    {
      "pid": "3",
      "detalle": "Mantecol",
      "id_marca": "3",
      "id_rubro": "2",
      "foto": null,
      "descripcion": "Postre a base de pasta de maní 25g",
      "bar_code": "7791249010549",
      "id_tipo": "1"
    },
    {
      "pid": "4",
      "detalle": "Harina 0000",
      "id_marca": "4",
      "id_rubro": "3",
      "foto": null,
      "descripcion": null,
      "bar_code": null,
      "id_tipo": "2"
    },
    {
      "pid": "5",
      "detalle": "Pompito",
      "id_marca": "5",
      "id_rubro": "2",
      "foto": null,
      "descripcion": null,
      "bar_code": "8413178144308",
      "id_tipo": "1"
    },
    {
      "pid": "6",
      "detalle": "Chocolate Blanco",
      "id_marca": "2",
      "id_rubro": "2",
      "foto": null,
      "descripcion": null,
      "bar_code": null,
      "id_tipo": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Busque muchos posts en stackoverflow pero ninguna de las respuestas me ayudaron por ahora, se que es un problema del array de objetos pero no estoy seguro como solucionarlo. Aqui mi codigo php

Obtener_Productos.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Obtiene todos los productos de la base de datos
 */

/**
 * Constantes para construcción de respuesta
 */
const DATOS = "productos";



require './productos_query.php';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    // Obtener productos de la base de datos
    $productos = productos_query::getAll();

    // Definir tipo de la respuesta
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if ($productos) {
        $datos[DATOS] = $productos;
        print json_decode(json_encode($datos),true);
    }
}
```

productos_query.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Representa el data de los productos
 * almacenados en la base de datos
 */
require 'mysql_connect.php';

class productos_query
{
    // Nombre de la tabla asociada a esta clase
    const TABLE_NAME = "productos";

    function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Obtiene todos los productos de la base de datos
     * @return array|bool Arreglo con todos los productos o false en caso de error
     */
    public static function getAll()
    {
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM " . self::TABLE_NAME;
        try {
            // Preparar sentencia
            $comando = mysql_connect::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
            // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
            $comando->execute();

            return $comando->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Como puedo devolver correctamente el array para poder evitar este problema?
Estoy convencido de que es mucho mas facil resolverlo desde php que desde android studio, asi que desde ya muchas gracias

Codigo java en android studio

Mainactivity.java

```
public void getFeed() {


        Call<List<Product>> listCall = mManager.getProductService().getAllProducts();

        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Product>>() {



            public void onResponse(Call<List<Product>> call, Response<List<Product>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    List<Product> ProductList = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.size(); i++) {
                        Product product = ProductList.get(i);

                        SaveIntoDatabase task = new SaveIntoDatabase();
                        task.execute(product);

                        mProductAdapter.addProduct(product);
                    }
                } else {
                    int sc = response.code();
                    switch (sc) {
                        case 400:
                            Log.e("Error 400", "Bad Request");
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            Log.e("Error 404", "Not Found");
                            break;
                        default:
                            Log.e("Error", "Generic Error");
                    }
                }
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }


            public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Product.java

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("pid")
    @Expose
    private int pid;
    @SerializedName("detalle")
    @Expose
    private String detalle;
    @SerializedName("id_marca")
    @Expose
    private int id_marca;
    @SerializedName("id_rubro")
    @Expose
    private int id_rubro;
    @SerializedName("foto")
    @Expose
    private Bitmap foto;
    @SerializedName("descripcion")
    @Expose
    private String descripcion;
    @SerializedName("bar_code")
    @Expose
    private String bar_code;
    @SerializedName("id_tipo")
    @Expose
    private int id_tipo;


    private boolean isFromDatabase;


    public int getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(int pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }


    public String getDetalle() { return detalle; }

    public void setDetalle(String detalle) { this.detalle = detalle; }

    public int getMarca() { return id_marca; }

    public void setMarca(int id_marca) { this.id_marca = id_marca; }

    public int getRubro() { return id_rubro; }

    public void setRubro(int id_rubro) { this.id_rubro = id_rubro; }

    public Bitmap getFoto() { return foto; }

    public void setFoto(Bitmap foto) { this.foto = foto; }

    public String getDescripcion() { return descripcion; }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) { this.descripcion = descripcion; }

    public String getBarcode() { return bar_code; }

    public void setBarcode(String bar_code) { this.bar_code = bar_code; }

    public int getTipo() { return id_tipo; }

    public void setTipo(int id_tipo) { this.id_tipo = id_tipo; }
```

Restmanager.java

```
public class RestManager {

    private ProductService mProductService;

    public ProductService getProductService() {
        if (mProductService == null) {

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.HTTP.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            mProductService = retrofit.create(ProductService.class);
        }
        return mProductService;
    }
}
```

ProductService.java

```
public interface ProductService {

    @GET("/celiarg/obtener_productos.php")

    Call<List<Product>> getAllProducts();

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! android studio es la ide que usas para programar, supongo que en java. el error quien lo tira?

Comment: La aplicacion, con un toast, especificamente esta linea                       public void onFailure(Call<List<Product>> call, Throwable t) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Comment: Creo que deberias mostrar ese lado de la app en tu pregunta. usa el boton [edit] y agrega el codigo donde da el error. Tambien suelen pedir en esta clase de preguntas el log

Comment: hecho.. voy a leer el post de como preguntar, el log dice lo mismo que el titulo, nada mas ni nada menos

Comment: @UlisesBravo, diría que el error puede deberse a como estas imprimiendo los datos en el archivo `Obtener_Productos.php`. Intenta hacerlo así `print json_encode($datos); die();`. Si te funciona, puedo crear una respuesta y explicar el porque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit espera un arreglo de productos y en su lugar recibe un objeto con una propiedad productos, esta propiedad productos si tiene como valor el arreglo de productos que Retrofit espera serializar.

Intenta cambiando esta linea en tu archivo PHP:

```
print json_decode(json_encode($datos),true);
```

Por esta:

```
print json_encode($productos);
```

Esto codificara el arreglo de productos directamente.